# com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$NotResolved: has not been resolved,

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I am trying to read the following config file using typesafe config

```
common = {
  jdbcDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  slickDriver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver"
  port = 3306
  db = "foo"
  user = "bar"
  password = "baz"
}

source = ${common} {server = "remoteserver"}
target = ${common} {server = "localserver"}
```

When I try to read my config using this code

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("src/main/resources/application.conf"))
val username = conf.getString("source.user")
```

I get an error

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$NotResolved: source.user has not been resolved, you need to call Config#resolve(), see API docs for Config#resolve()
```

I don't get any error if I put everything inside "source" or "target" tags. I get errors only when I try to use "common"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved it myself.

```
ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("src/main/resources/application.conf")).resolve()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
Config confSwitchEnv = ConfigFactory.load("env.conf");
```

the `env.conf` is in the `resources` dir.

reference: https://nicedoc.io/lightbend/config